# Threejs - Update light color dinamically / each frame

Tags: three.js

I am trying to change the color of a DirectionalLight based on the theme of the webpage, either Light mode or Night Mode, it works but you have to refresh the webpage in order to see the changes

Here is my code which reads a hex color from a JSON of styled-components and then convert it to a ThreeJS color like 0xffffff

```
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(
      new THREE.Color(theme.background),
      0.6
    );
    directionalLight.position.set(-10, 10, 5);
    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    directionalLight.shadow.bias = -0.0005;
    scene.add(directionalLight);
```

is there a way to update the light each frame so i can see the change in real time?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update the light’s [.color property](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=direc#api/en/lights/Light.color). For example, this will update the color to orange:

```js
directionalLight.color.set(0xff9900);
```

This way you can switch the light’s color without having to refresh the page.